# UI-Select doesn't show selected value

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to bind a UI-Select control to a Class[] list. Filling it up works properly, but when i select an item, the selected item will not show. Any fix for this?

This is my ui-select :

```
<ui-select ng-model="vm._classId" theme="bootstrap">
                                                <ui-select-match placeholder="- Select class -">{{$select.selected.text}}</ui-select-match>
                                                <ui-select-choices repeat="class.ClassId as class in vm._classes">
                                                    <span ng-bind-html="class.ClassName"></span>
                                                </ui-select-choices>
                                            </ui-select>
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Are you sure you have items in `_classes`? What if you show them in the page `{{ vm._classes }}` do you see them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because this code here `{{$select.selected.text}}`. i think `text` property does not exist so  `{{$select.selected.text}}` to `{{$select.selected.ClassName}}`

Comment: Oww , yeah i skipped everytime this part of code when i'm trying to figure out what's the problem. thanks a lot @Miqe